# Logistic Regression and Sparse matrices -AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Tags: sparse-matrix, logistic-regression, attributeerror, deprecation-warning

I am trying to use logistic regression with sparse matrices, because it may work faster. Problem is, I get errors and warnings that I do not understand. I will show you some code. I warn you, I am new to this, so if you can pinpoint any unnecessary-bad code of me, please say so.

My logic is the following: (I will present code as well if written text does not help at all)
1) Train_set and test_set all at one set to perform the preprocessing at once (fill gaps, onehotencdoing etc) and to transform everything in sparse form
2) Then, after preprocessing, I need to slice this set into the 2 sets, one for train (to make the model) and the test (which I want to predict)
3) To slice though, I transform from coo to csr, otherwise I cannot do it.
4) After I sliced, I do the usual for modelling and then problems occur.

Time to show some code:

```
# read csv
train_set = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep=',', nrows=10000,  keep_default_na=True)
test_set = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', nrows=10000,  keep_default_na=True)
```

```
#all_set includes both train & read data
all_set = pd.concat([train_set, test_set], sort=False)
```

```
# Pass values of train_set to X
X = all_set[all_set.columns]
X = X.drop(['id', 'target'], axis=1)
```

```
# Pass target values to Y and convert it to a sparse matrix
Y = train_set['target']
Y = sparse.csr_matrix(Y)
Y = csr_matrix.transpose(Y)
```

(after preprocessing)

```
# Seperate data into Train and Test with preprocessing complete
# first I transform coo to csr (fro new_Train) because for coo slicing is unavailable
csr_Train = new_Train.tocsr()
final_train_set = csr_Train[0:len(train_set['target']), :]
final_test_set = csr_Train[len(train_set['target']):all_set.shape[0], :]
```

Y contains my target column to use for training and
final_train_set is my train data

```
print("shape and type", final_train_set.shape, type(final_train_set))
print("shape and type", Y.shape, type(Y))
```

Results: (***edit: Even if both were coo or both were csr, I got the same errors and warnings***)
[image]

Seeing the same shape and all, all optimistic I proceed to modelling.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(final_train_set, Y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)

lr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')

lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The shape and type are the same. And here are the results...

```
C:\Users\kosta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:724: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
C:\Users\kosta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py:192: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  return X != X
C:\Users\kosta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py:192: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  return X != X
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kosta/PycharmProjects/cat_dat/Cat_Dat_v2.py", line 110, in <module>
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\kosta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1532, in fit
    accept_large_sparse=solver != 'liblinear')
  File "C:\Users\kosta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 725, in check_X_y
    _assert_all_finite(y)
  File "C:\Users\kosta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 59, in _assert_all_finite
    if _object_dtype_isnan(X).any():
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

To be honest, I don't understand what's wrong (neither the warnings nor the errors) and I don't know how to proceed, apart from many trials and researching on net that I did for hours. So any help will do!

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was with the target column. I should have not converted it at sparse form. I should have left it as a pandasSeries. It seems that for model to work, the 2 arguments don't need to be of the same type.